# Printing elements in a array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

I am trying to get an output similar to this -

> John Smith has been added to the student list
>
> Tom Will has been added to the student list
>
> your name has been added to the student list
>
> --Begin--
>
> Name:John Smith Email:js@qmul.ac.uk Year:2008
>
> Name:Tom Will Email:tw@qmul.ac.uk Year:2007
>
> Name:your name Email:your email Year:your year
>
> --End--
>
> Tom Will has been removed from the student list
>
> --Begin--
>
> Name:John Smith Email:js@qmul.ac.uk Year:2008
>
> Name:your name Email:your email Year: your year
>
> --End--

But it is printing it muddled up. Where am I going wrong in my code?

A class that represents a student:

```
public class Student { 

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int year; //year of registration to the course

    /**
     *  Constructor
     *
     *@param  name, email and year of registration
     */
    public Student(String name, String email, int year){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.year = year;
    }

    /**
     *  get the name
     *
     *@return the name
     */
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    /**
     *  A toString() method to give a String representation of a Student
     *
     *@return    The String representation of a Student
     */
    public String toString(){
        return "Name:" + name +" Email:" + email + " Year:" + year;
    }

}

public class StudentList {

    private ArrayList<Student> list; //instance variable

    /**
     *  Constructor
     */
    public StudentList(){
        list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    /**
     *  a method to print off all ArrayList elements
     */

    public void printList(){
        System.out.println("--Begin--");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }       
        System.out.println("--End--");

    }

    /**
     *  A method to add a student to the list
     *
     *@param    The student
     */
    public void addToList(Student s){
        list.add(s);

        System.out.println("--Begin--");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) +"has been addded to the list");
            }
        System.out.println("--End--");

    }

    /**
     *  A method to remove a student from the list
     *
     *@param    The student
     */
    public void removeFromList(Student s){
        list.remove(s);
        System.out.println("--Begin--");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) +"has been removed from the list");
        }
        System.out.println("--End--");

    }

    /**
     *  A main method to test
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an instance of the class 
        StudentList studentList = new StudentList();

        //create 3 student objects
        Student s1 = new Student("John Smith", "js@qmul.ac.uk", 2008);
        Student s2 = new Student("Tom Will", "tw@qmul.ac.uk", 2007);
        Student s3 =  new Student("Cameron Young","Cammyoung@live.co.uk",2018);

        //add the three students to the list
        studentList.addToList(s1);
        studentList.addToList(s2);
        studentList.addToList(s3);

        // Print the list
        studentList.printList();

        // Remove the student "Tom Will"
        studentList.removeFromList(s2);

        // Print the list again
        studentList.printList();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show how it's "muddled up"?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the whole list every time you add or remove a user. I assume that's what you mean by "muddled up".

Here's what your `addToList` method should look like:

```
public void addToList(Student s) {
    list.add(s);    
    System.out.println(s.getName() + " has been addded to the list");           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addToList and removeFromList you printing all students in collection.You can remove cycle and use only parameter. And use getName() to print only name